# Laravel single page application with asset routes

Tags: laravel

I am developing a single page application that people can upload file to the website in the WIXIWIG editor, but when you go to the public link for the asset you are directed to the wildcard page that consists of the app itself instead of showing the asset.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'AppController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Is there a way to store the files locally and have the asset files and other type of files not go to this route?

For example going to a url like this

```
/storage/media/38aOL4Pp092SAqNeKIkTuVQ8qRE2RGhfEp2KHSP9.png
```

Does not show this image but shows the single page application, and it will load images from other websites perfectly fine.

Comment: You can change the `asset()` helper url in your [.env](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L57)

Comment: I can load images from other websites just not local images since the image path go to the catch all route and renders the app view

Comment: As long as `/storage/media/38aOL4Pp092SAqNeKIkTuVQ8qRE2RGhfEp2KHSP9.png` is an actual file, its existence should take precedence over Laravel's routing, as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is in the `.htaccess`. (The recommended nginx config does a similar thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel should already prioritize real, extant files over its own routing. In the default Apache config:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Or in nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Both configs basically say "try to find a real file, and fall back on `index.php` **only if** you don't find anything".

Unless you've done something wonky with these configs, this means that `/storage/media/38aOL4Pp092SAqNeKIkTuVQ8qRE2RGhfEp2KHSP9.png` isn't the right path for that file.

It's important to note that your app's `storage` directory isn't publicly accessible (if you've configured things properly). See the Laravel docs on [the public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) and make sure you've got a link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`, and that `storage/app/public/media/38aOL4Pp092SAqNeKIkTuVQ8qRE2RGhfEp2KHSP9.png` exists on your server (and is readable by the webserver).

Answer (score 0):

Define a route with a parameter (e.g. `'/files/{fileName}'`) before the wildcard route and return the requested file with that route.

Then, put the wildcard route (which returns the index view with the single-page app) at the bottom of route definitions. That way you will return the single-page app only if the route does not correspond to any defined above.

All in all, it should look something like this:

```
Route::get('files/{fileName}', function ($fileName) {
    // return the requested file
});

Route::get('/{any}', 'AppController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: I'd note, though, that doing it this way means the requests go through Laravel, which is going to be a lot less performant than serving it as raw static files directly from the webserver.